# cannot pass variable with value things.png via GET method in url

Tags: php, get

I have 4 values I wanna send via GET like this :

```
<a href="aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=$r[id_produk]&namafile=$r[gambar]">
    Delete
</a>
```

the URL should looks like this right

```
website/aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=198&namafile=thing.png
```

but instead it looks like this `/aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=198`

I'm missing one value which is `namafile`. it seems I need to use `urlencode()` ? but how and where do i need to put it ?

**edit**

this is the full code for this

```
$no = $posisi+1;
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($tampil)){
   $tanggal=tgl_indo($r[tgl_masuk]);
   $harga=format_rupiah($r[harga]);
   $namafile=urlencode($r[gambar]);
     echo "<tr><td>$no</td>
            <td>$r[nama_produk]</td>
            <td align=center>$r[harga]</td>
            <td align=center>$r[potongan]</td>
            <td align=center>$r[stok]</td>
            <td>$tanggal</td>
             <td><a 
               href=?module=produk&act=editproduk&id=$r[id_produk]><img src='images/icn_edit.png' title='Edit'>
                </a>  
              <a 
                 href=$aksi?module=produk&act=hapus&id=$r[id_produk]&namafile=$namafile><img src='images/icn_trash.png' title='delete'>
              </a>
       </td>
     </tr>";
  $no++;
}
```

Comment: I tried this : 
$namafile=urlencode($r[gambar]);
aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=$r[id_produk]&namafile=$namafile

still not working thouhg

Comment: what you get after execute `$namafile=urlencode($r[gambar]);`    `print_r($namafile);`

Comment: something like this 37corona+wire+0.8.jpg.

Comment: wait it's working now, but it never worked before

Comment: you can use `$file=urldecode($namafile); print_r($file);`

Comment: oooh so if I wanna unlink a file I decode it before passing the value so it will looks like 37corona wire 08.jpg instead of 37corona+wire+08.jpg right? thank you verymuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please encode before you pass the variable.

```
$namafile=urlencode($r[gambar]);
<a href="aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=$r[id_produk]&namafile=$namafile">
Delete
</a>
```

in the sending page,

```
$_GET["namafile"]
$file=urldecode($namafile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add quotes and urlencode

```
<a href="aksi_produk.php?module=produk&act=hapus&id=<?php echo $r['id_produk'];?>&namafile=<?php echo urlencode($r['gambar']);?>">
Delete
</a>
```

Comment: but id_produk gets sent even without quotes
I'll try with namafile

Answer (score 0):

You can pass image name after encoding it with any algorithm.

For example

$namafile=base64_encode($r[gambar]);

While your accessing this value decode it with base64_decode();

Try this hope this will work..